# CXF Web Service WSDL File Not Found Exception

Tags: web-services, cxf

i had tried to develop a web service using eclipse indigo but there is error after generating wsdl file (java2ws) it display error on Test Service Explorere wizard which result previous generate wsdl file been erase. Thus, I'm manually copy the wsdl file to temp folder and copy back to the desire folder but following error is display when invoke from browser.

Error:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:90)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:687)
    com.peter.client.CreditCardServiceClient.createServiceClient(CreditCardServiceClient.java:43)
    com.peter.controller.CreditCardController.doPost(CreditCardController.java:106)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
root cause

org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:90)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:687)
    com.peter.client.CreditCardServiceClient.createServiceClient(CreditCardServiceClient.java:43)
    com.peter.controller.CreditCardController.doPost(CreditCardController.java:106)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
root cause

javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'localhost:8080/CreditCardService/CreditcardService?WSDL'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: localhost:8080/CreditCardService/CreditcardService?WSDL
    com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:239)
    org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:186)
    org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:90)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:687)
    com.peter.client.CreditCardServiceClient.createServiceClient(CreditCardServiceClient.java:43)
    com.peter.controller.CreditCardController.doPost(CreditCardController.java:106)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
root cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: localhost:8080/CreditCardService/CreditcardService?WSDL
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1434)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:986)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:143)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:802)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:230)
    org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:285)
    com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:239)
    org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:186)
    org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:90)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:687)
    com.peter.client.CreditCardServiceClient.createServiceClient(CreditCardServiceClient.java:43)
    com.peter.controller.CreditCardController.doPost(CreditCardController.java:106)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.
```

[image: Error Screen]

This is the exception for the screen shot.
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

```
Error
Wed Aug 22 19:29:09 SGT 2012
Unexpected exception (com.ibm.rational.ttt.common.ui.dialogs.wimport.WImportUtil)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to access localhost:8080/CreditCardWebService/services/CreditCardServicePort?wsdl
    at com.ibm.rational.ttt.common.ui.dialogs.wimport.WImportUtil.createFile(WImportUtil.java:402)
    at com.ibm.rational.ttt.common.ui.dialogs.wimport.WImportUtil.importUri(WImportUtil.java:346)
    at com.ibm.rational.ttt.common.ui.dialogs.wimport.WImportUtil.importSomethingRunnable(WImportUtil.java:218)
    at com.ibm.rational.ttt.common.ui.dialogs.wimport.WImportUtil$1.run(WImportUtil.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at com.ibm.rational.ttt.common.ui.dialogs.wimport.WImportUtil.importSomething(WImportUtil.java:134)
    at com.ibm.rational.ttt.ustc.api.GSC.importWSDL(GSC.java:108)
    at com.ibm.rational.ttt.ustc.api.GSC.importWSDL(GSC.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.gsc.internal.GSCUtils.getWSDLFile(GSCUtils.java:156)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.gsc.internal.GSCDialog.loadWSDL(GSCDialog.java:69)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.gsc.internal.GSCDialog.createDialogArea(GSCDialog.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.gsc.internal.GSCLaunchCommand.launchExternally(GSCLaunchCommand.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.gsc.internal.GSCLaunchCommand.execute(GSCLaunchCommand.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.widgets.test.WSDLTestLaunchCommand.commandFactoryExecution(WSDLTestLaunchCommand.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.widgets.test.WSDLTestLaunchCommand.execute(WSDLTestLaunchCommand.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.creation.ui.widgets.test.ServiceTestWidget.handleLaunchButton(ServiceTestWidget.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.creation.ui.widgets.test.ServiceTestWidget.access$0(ServiceTestWidget.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.creation.ui.widgets.test.ServiceTestWidget$1.widgetSelected(ServiceTestWidget.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Is there a way to generate wsdl manually?

I tried typing the java2s but it say the command is not recognize 
as internal program.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve by remove the generation of RequestWrapper and deployment success.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone stumbling here on 2022.
I was seeing similar issues with gradleTask using apache cxf plugin.

go through the command line options and add parameter -wsdlLocation with value of the path of wsdl in classpath.